# Django image insertion in Admin

Tags: django, image, content-management-system

I am building a small side project - a simple news site. I want to use the Django Admin for uploading articles and allow access to non-coders so as they can publish articles a la Wordpress or such. I have added some functionality to the admin, first trying out TinyMCE and Dojo rich text editors. However, these do not come with the ability to insert an image into an article from a file (just urls).

I really only want some light text formatting in the text area plus the ability to upload and insert images from the users's harddrive directly into the article. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already using [django-tinymce](http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/), you can integrate [django-filebrowser](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser) with it. See [django-tinymce's documentation](http://django-tinymce.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.5/docs/.build/html/installation.html#id2).
There is also a [commercial choice](http://www.binpress.com/app/tinymce-image-uploader--manager/23) which looks good, but I have never tested it.